# How do I migrate data (nodes, users, and images)?

Tags: 8, migrations, upgrading

What is the best way to migrate the following data from Drupal 5 to Drupal 8?

- Nodes (different content types)
- Nodes with images
- Usernodes (this is a special node type in Drupal 5)
- User accounts
- User profiles
- Images (special content type)

I want to setup a total new installation of Drupal 8 and then import the data from my old Drupal 5 site (which is still online).

There are a lot of migrate modules (in Drupal 8 Core) and other helpful modules (e.g. feeds, node import), but I do **not** want to migrate data with 2 steps.

What is the best way to migrate the data directly from the Drupal 5 database into my Drupal 8 installation?

Thank you.

Comment: There's many ways to do this (probably too broad/opinionated here). But the TL;DR is use the migration module/framework when you can't tolerate data loss and you want direct control of the process, and use import tools (e.g. Feeds, node import, etc) when you can tolerate some data loss.

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you will require some coding skills (or maybe you can hire a programmer). You might have to do one or more of the following:

- Setup a fresh Drupal 8 site.
- Study and [learn how to use the D8 migrate module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-api-overview) which is a part of the Drupal 8 core.

  - A few months ago I wrote some detailed [tutorials on D8 migrations](https://evolvingweb.ca/blog/drupal-8-migration-migrating-basic-data-part-1), if you want to read them.
  - Here's a [tutorial on Drupal 6 to Drupal 8 migration](https://evolvingweb.ca/blog/migrate-translated-content-drupal-6-drupal-8). Drupal 5 to Drupal 8 should be similar.
- Implement and execute migrations for all objects you want to import into D8.
- Review the data which gets migrated into D8 and manually (or write more code) fix issues, if any.

I don't know if there exists any way to do an easy D5 > D6 migration? If yes, then consider migrating your data to D6 first and then use the D8 core migration modules to import the D6 stuff into D8. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I will read your tutorial later on.  I think it must be possible to export the nodes and data from Drupal 5 database with phpmyadmin (e.g. as csv data). And then import it with a module into Drupal 8.  Do you think this is a good way?

Comment: That sounds good. However, if you make regular updates to the D5 site, you must stop making updates to the site at one point before the final migration. Also, if you are planning to migrate, users, taxonomies, nodes and bunch of other stuff, you will end up with many files! It will be much easier if you directly do a migration from the database.

Comment: Yes and how can I do a migration directly form the database? I do not want to write much code, is it possible to do it without much coding?

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to write substantial amount of code.

Comment: I am sure I will not!

Comment: Good thing if you don't have to! Good luck! And a happy weekend!